# How to prevent loading of XML-views in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I've paid attention that some implementations of the UI5-based apps prevent of loading XML-views (templates) and I can't get an XML-view via the DevTools' Network tab, e.g.:

- https://discovery-center.cloud.sap
- https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com

While other implementations load the XML-view and only after that parses it in a browser:

- https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/walkthrough/37/webapp/test/mockServer.html

How to protect my UI5-app source code and to prevent from the UI5 app loading the XML-view as it appears in IDE?

Is it a matter of the UI5 Tooling configuration?
I know, there is a dedicated step in [UI5 Tooling Builder](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/):

> (7/8) Running task uglify...

But it looks like, it doesn't prevent from loading XML-views «as is».

Comment: There seems to be a [minifier task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui5-task-minify-xml) for the `@ui5/builder`. Maybe if you add it to `ui5.yaml`, it does the trick? This is something I've been wondering myself, but haven't tested.

Comment: About link 1: if you inspect [the Component-preload](https://pasteboard.co/u2mmcEpdvAQM.png) you can see the `XML` views are [also bundled there](https://pasteboard.co/u3aAflKp9gsE.png), [formatted source example of Estimate.view.xml](https://pastebin.com/jbdQe9N0).
About link 2: in the `resources` folder, you can find all the pre-formatted static assets, [link](https://shorturl.at/euRYZ).

So the `XML` files are not really gone, just hidden from the network tab. I would also be happy to know why, esp. if it is an easy configuration win. But if someone wants to find the `XML` files, he will

Comment: @fmi21, I guess that's the way how UI5 reduces amount of requests by bundling the files into one big file with UI5 Tooling.

Comment: Why would you want to protect frontend source code? Using the diagnostics tool (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `S`) you can literally export any control/view as nicely formatted XML.

Comment: @Marc, actually, I wanted to perform a reverse engineering of https://discovery-center.cloud.sap/missions/, to extract a «view as nicely formatted XML», but then I paid attention that I don't see an XML there, although it's an UI5-based site.

Comment: You mean this? [App.view.xml](https://gist.github.com/OTTOxMarc/dfbbacccba61da1faac301ce113d56a0) which embeds [Missions.view.xml](https://gist.github.com/OTTOxMarc/b390c5ea2bb0ad8e4c01240255ab5fde)

Comment: As to why you don't see them in the network tab, like @fmi21 said these apps are minified. Your third link (mockserver walkthrough) is not minified (Component-preload is requested but cannot be loaded) so it fetches all necessary files individually.

Comment: @Marc, how did you extract these XMLs?

Comment: As I said open the diagnostics tool. In the `Control Tree` select the desired view. On the right side you should see an *Export* tab

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of `Export to XML` functionality of the UI5 Diagnostics tool. Please, consider arranging your response as an answer, so I can mark it as a correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [**@Marc**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083921/marc) for sharing this knowledge! I arrange his info as the proper answer.

The UI5 Tooling proposes an option to minify a codebase of an UI5 app. However, it's still possible to reverse engineer the minified version and to download the original XML-templates with the help of UI5 Diagnostic Tools:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, a UI5 Diagnostic Tools pop up should rise up
2. Go to `Control Tree` section
3. Choose the desired view, on the right side of the popup, click on the `Export` tab
4. Choose the desired format for exporting: `Export to XML` or `Export to HTML`.

P.S. Perhaps worth pointing out that it's possible to prevent activating UI5 Tooling by setting in the HTML bootstrap script the `productive`-flag to `true`:

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window["sap-ui-config"] = {
        "productive" : true
    };
</script>
```

It might complicate a little reverse engineering of an UI5 application.